# Can I use annotations for service class in symfony-2.0?

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

Just to Java Spring Hibernate.

If I want to make service class, can I use annotations like `@service`?

Do I have to use PHP yml files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can with [JMSDIExtraBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle).

Comment: Is there any example where someone has used these annotations. I have read the docs but could not fully understood how to use them

Comment: You can check [this controller](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle/blob/master/Controller/TranslateController.php)